# Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered query

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, xampp, sqlsrv

Good day, I'm trying to `run queries` for my `searching`

but i get this result

> Error Number: IMSSP/-59
>
> Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for
>   buffered query

Here it's my query

```
SELECT * From transaksi a 
left join Outlet b on a.Outlet = b.OutletCode
left join area c on b.areacode = c.areacode where b.BrandCode like  '%AR-1%'
and b.areacode like '%%' and b.OutletCode like '%%' and tanggal 
between '2016-03-01' and '2016-07-31'
```

from my query above I get `16046 rows`.

-- A Test --

when I try to do some other search that only show `10 rows`, that error not showing.

```
SELECT * From transaksi a 
left join Outlet b on a.Outlet = b.OutletCode
left join area c on b.areacode = c.areacode where b.BrandCode like  '%AR-1%'
and b.areacode like '%%' and b.OutletCode like '%K-SRLM%' and tanggal 
between '2016-05-01' and '2016-05-10'
```

here it's not using `range` showing `411 rows`

```
SELECT * From transaksi a 
left join Outlet b on a.Outlet = b.OutletCode
left join area c on b.areacode = c.areacode where b.BrandCode like  '%AR-1%'
and b.areacode like '%%' and b.OutletCode like '%K-SRLM%'
```

Here it's my fullscript.

```
function show_it()
    {
        extract(populateform());
        if($date_search == "")
        {
            unset($date_search);
        }
        if(isset($date_search)){
        $explode = explode('-',$date_search);
        $start_date = inggris_date($explode[0]);
        $end_date = inggris_date($explode[1]);
        $result = $this->modelmodel->showdata("SELECT * From transaksi a 
                                                left join Outlet b on a.Outlet = b.OutletCode
                                                left join area c on b.areacode = c.areacode where b.BrandCode like  '%$tipenya%'
                                                and b.areacode like '%$area%' and b.OutletCode like '%$outlet%' and tanggal 
                                                between '$start_date' and '$end_date'
                                                ");
        }else{
        $result = $this->modelmodel->showdata("SELECT * From transaksi a 
                                                left join Outlet b on a.Outlet = b.OutletCode
                                                left join area c on b.areacode = c.areacode where b.BrandCode like '%$tipenya%'
                                                and b.areacode like '%$area%' and b.OutletCode like '%$outlet%' 
                                                ");
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding 'Memory limit' issue:
   either increase your memory limit from setting or add limit in your query.
2. Let us know which query gives you 10 rows only.your 1st query search only those result where BrandCode like  '%AR-1%' between provided date. May be other query satisfy only 10 results.

Comment: Did you check manually how many records satisfy the  conditions because system search data which satisfy BrandCode like '%AR-1%'   and  OutletCode like '%K-SRLM%'?

Comment: without range date , the result showing `411 rows`.

Comment: we need to check it with date range or comment the date part from your script & check the result